# Require input if there are any

Tags: forms, input-fields

My client is registering customer data and wants to make sure that they register their customers e-mail addresses when ever a customer has one. So the input textbox should be required to have valid data. If the customer does not have an e-mail address the user should be able to indicate that the e-mail textbox has not been forgotten but there simply isn't any data to enter in it.

A checkbox beneath the input could be added and when checked the user is indicating to the system that the field has been considered and it is just not relevant a the time.

I'm interested in hearing if you have any alternative solutions to this.

UPDATE:
The clients employees fills in this data. The customers are not identified by e-mail, it's just a convenience data, which they would like whenever available.
I've come to at conclusion that a required field that really isn't required doesn't exist. Either it is or it is not. The real problem is a too long form, stopping the users scan of the form before reaching the e-mail field.

Thank you for your replies, they made me rethink the problem and see the root of it.

Comment: Does your client realise that whatever solution you come up with, someone could easily claim they don't have an email address when they actually do, but just don't want to provide it?

Comment: This is closely related to [A required field that isn't really required](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60919/a-required-field-that-isnt-really-required).

Comment: @JonW I second you. I have not seen any website recently which doesn't require e-mail id of the user. In most of the cases this is the highest priority field.